# How can I turn a family tree on Geni.com into a printable PDF report?

Tags: gedcom, myheritage.com, family-tree-builder, geni.com

I've been building a family tree on Geni.com. How can I turn that into a printable report, including all profile photos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Export the GEDCOM from Geni.com

   1. Click on https://www.geni.com/gedcom/export
   2. Select the Export Forest option, and follow instructions.
   3. Wait for your GEDCOME file to be created (you will be notified by email).
   4. Download the GEDCOM file.
2. Remove non-ASCII characters from GEDCOM file

   1. If your GEDCOM file contains non-ASCII characters, you'll have to remove them to generate the report (at least as of Family Tree Builder 8.0.0.8457)
   2. A simple regex to find non-ASCII chars is: `[^\x00-\xFF]`
3. Import the GEDCOM file on myheritage.com

   1. If you have a family tree with many pictures, you may reach myheritage.com's free account limit (500MB). If you do, you can sign up for a free trial and immediately cancel it to remove the size limit.
   2. Upload a GEDCOM on the [Import tree (GEDCOM) page](https://www.myheritage.com/FP/upload-gedcom-file.php).
   3. Change permission settings so it isn't world-viewable and searchable
   4. Ensure you are also logged on the Geni while importing to ensure your photos are correctly imported.
4. Import the tree into MyHeritage's [FamilyTreeBuilder](https://www.myheritage.com/family-tree-builder)

   1. Install FamilyTreeBuilder
   2. Click on File -> Restore Project -> Restore from Online Family Site
   3. The entire tree, including all pictures, will now be downloaded
5. Generate the report

   1. Right click on the subject of interest for your report and click "Book Report"
6. Store for future modifications

   1. Click File -> Back Up Project to generate a zip file backup
   2. Copy the FamilyTreeBuilder installer and the zip file to a cloud storage and a DVD so that the tree is self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use FamilyTreeBuilder to create your report. You can use any of the many Family Tree programmes both free and paid to import your gedcom file to, you will still need to export it as detailed in @Moshe's reply. You could also consider using a programme such as [The Complete Genealogy Reporter](http://www.tcgr.bufton.org/) if you just want a report.

Comment: There are many family tree programs that support importing an existing GEDCOM file. The issues were that 1) Geni.com exported a GEDCOM file that GRAMPS (and a second program I tested) failed to import, and 2) even applications that could import the GEDCOM didn't associate the pictures with the family members. I didn't want to manually re-associate the portraits. If you can recommend a specific solution that would support importing a geni.com GEDCOM, maintaining the associated pictures, and generating a report, I'm all ears.